# Strange results using maps package to create a choropleth map with clipped boundaries

Tags: r, maps, choropleth

When I map all the counties of New York, I get a correct choropleth map. However, when I clip the map, the colors become seemingly random. Here is an example where I am just grouping the counties into 5 categories based on the county name.

```
library(maps)
library(mapproj)
library(RColorBrewer)

map1 <- map("county", region="New York", plot=FALSE)
ny <- c(1:62)
ny2 <- data.frame(ny)

#define map colors
clr <- (brewer.pal(5, "Spectral"))

#define quantiles
map2 <- within(ny2, quartile <- as.integer(cut(ny, quantile(ny,probs=0:5/5), include.lowest=TRUE)))
map2$colorbuckets <- cut(map2$quartile, breaks=5)


#all of ny - colors are correct
map("county", border="gray", regions = "New York", fill=TRUE, projection="simpleconic", 
par=c(30,45), col=clr[map2$colorbuckets])
box()

#subset of ny - colors are not correct, seemingly random
map("county", regions="New York", xlim=c(-74.5,-73), ylim=c(40.48,43.9),  
border="gray", fill=TRUE, exact=TRUE, col=clr[map2$colorbuckets])
box()
```

Comment: OK, I figured out that the colors on the subset map are not random. My inset map shows all or part of 28 counties, while the colors are based on the first 28 counties in the full list. I have to subset the full list to just those counties in the inset map, which requires a few steps including a merge.

Answer (score 0):

```
#this code works 

library(maps)
library(mapproj)
library(RColorBrewer)

nymap <- map("county", region="New York", plot=FALSE)
ny <- c(1:62)
ny2 <- data.frame(ny)

#define map colors
clr <- (brewer.pal(5, "Spectral"))

#define quantiles
ny3 <- within(ny2, quartile <- as.integer(cut(ny, quantile(ny,probs=0:5/5), include.lowest=TRUE)))
ny3$colorbuckets <- cut(map2$quartile, breaks=5)
ny3$names <- nymap$names 

#all of ny - colors are correct
map("county", border="gray", regions = "New York", fill=TRUE, projection="simpleconic", 
    par=c(30,45), col=clr[nymap$colorbuckets])
box()

#create inset map, don't plot it but use it to merge with the complete list of county names and colors
inset1 <- map("county", regions="New York", xlim=c(-74.5,-73), ylim=c(40.48,43.9), plot=FALSE)
inset2 <- data.frame(inset1$names)
inset3 <- rename(inset2, c(inset1.names="names"))
inset4 <- merge(ny3,inset3,by="names")


#plot inset map - colors are now correct
map("county", regions="New York", xlim=c(-74.5,-73), ylim=c(40.48,43.9),  
    border="gray", fill=TRUE, col=clr[inset4$colorbuckets])
box()
```